# Stack push, pop, peek algorithms in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, stack

I understand how stacks work, but I have to write methods for push, pop and peek and then implement them in a driver class.  This is where it gets confusing.  Here is my `Stack` class:

```
public class Stack implements StackInterface
{
    private final int ARRAY_SIZE = 9;
    private String[] movies = new String[ARRAY_SIZE];   // Hold movie titles
    private int top = 0;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param moviesIn
     */

    public Stack(String[] moviesIn)
    {
        movies = moviesIn;
    }

    /**
     * Test for full stack
     */

    public void push(String moviesIn)
    {
        if (top >= movies.length)
            System.out.println("ERROR: Stack is full");

        top++;
        movies[top] = moviesIn;
    }

    /**
     * Test for empty stack
     */

    public String pop()
    {
        if (top == 0) {
                System.out.println("ERROR: Stack is empty");
                return " ";
        }

        top--;
        return movies[top];
    }

    public void peek()
    {
        // ???
    }
}
```

Here is what I have in my `main()` method so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String[] movies = {"Amour", "*Argo", "Beasts of the Southern Wild", "Django Unchained", "Les Misérables", "Life of Pi", "Lincoln", "Silver Linings Playbook", "Zero Dark Thirty"};
    Stack oscarStack = new Stack(movies);

    oscarStack.push(movies);
}
```

I thought I could just pass an object to the stack, but it doesn't seem to work that way.  So how do I push the `oscarStack` object onto the stack?  Or do I have to push each string individually?  In continuing my online research, it seems a stack constructor can only create an empty stack.  Is this why I cannot pass an object argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In main, you're placing all of your elements into the backing array implicitly without any push operations.  What you'd likely want to do is iterate over the movies you want to push, then push them in.

Two changes should be made:

- Change your Stack object to no longer accept an array of Strings.  This is confusing and unnecessary as all of the initialization is done on construction.
- There are two bugs with your `push`:

  - You don't account for the case in which the array is empty.  Switch around your incrementation of top, or use `movies[top++]`.
  - You don't actually *prevent* code execution if the array is full.  You'll get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if you try to run with what you've got.

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
   String[] movies = {"Amour", "*Argo", "Beasts of the Southern Wild", "Django Unchained", "Les Misérables", "Life of Pi", "Lincoln", "Silver Linings Playbook", "Zero Dark Thirty"};
    Stack oscarStack = new Stack();

    for(String movie : movies) {
        oscarStack.push(movie);
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, I was actually about to post with the two changes you suggested, so glad I'm on the right track.  However, I didn't just switch the top++ and movies[top].  I placed them in a else statement because I figured if the stack is full, display a message stating so, or else add the movie and increment top.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to push each element of the array onto the stack:

```
for (String movie : movies) {
    oscarStack.push(movie);
}
```

Alternatively, you could write a "pushAll" method in your `Stack` class that accepts a string array and basically does the same thing.

However, you seem to already be setting the movies array in the constructor, so I don't see the purpose of the call to `push`. Perhaps you can explain further.

P.S. You seem to have a bug in your push method:

```
public void push(String moviesIn)
{
    if (top >= movies.length)
        System.out.println("ERROR: Stack is full");

    top++;
    movies[top] = moviesIn;
}
```

With this code, there's no way that `movies[0]` will ever be assigned a value.

Comment: Every movie is already *in* the stack, per OP's constructor, though.

Comment: @Makoto - True. There seems no purpose to pushing the entire array again. Perhaps OP can explain further what the objective is for that call. Maybe it's just that `top` is left at its default value of 0 by the constructor.

Comment: Ted, I fixed the bug in the push method.  Thanks.  I have to admit I've been floundering and searching the Internet for help.  When I looked at it, I knew immediately what was wrong.  Clearly, I can't learn anything if I just cut and paste.  I do that to understand the concept and then write my own code.

Answer (score 0):

The push method expects a string as an argument and not an array of strings so you can either change the push method to accept string arrays as argument or pass one string at a time to your current push method.
Also you are not pushing oscarStack object and if you want to push any object the again the method signature should support that.

Comment: Ya, I tried that, but I kept getting errors--change back to String, change to String[].  It works now with me doing the for-each loop.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the answers given here, also remember to null the reference that was popped from the stack.
Here is a quote from the book 'Effective Java '

> Generally speaking, whenever a class manages its own memory, the
>   programmer should be alert for memory leaks. Whenever an element is
>   freed, any object references contained in the element should be nulled
>   out.

A sample copied from the book:

```
public Object pop() {
       if (size==0) throw new EmptyStackException();
       Object result = elements[--size];
       elements[size] = null; // Eliminate obsolete reference
       return result;
}
```

Comment: Atul, not sure what you mean.

Comment: @stef2dotoh Take a look at this: http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/java/9780137150021/creating-and-destroying-objects/ch02lev1sec6

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `Stack` data structure and you don't want to incur the cost of `Synchronization` then you can use `Dequeue`. `Stack` class available in Java extends `Vector`.

```
    Deque<Integer> q=new LinkedList<Integer>();
    q.offerFirst(Integer.SIZE);
    q.offerFirst(Integer.SIZE);
    q.pollFirst();
```

This is the most efficient stack implementation that is available in Java collection framework.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably initialize your variable as top=-1.Note that I have not initialized a constructor for this class Stack since its not compulsory to do so.If no user-defined constructor is provided for a class, compiler initializes member variables to its default values.

1.numeric data types are set to 0.
2.char data types are set to null character(‘\0’).
3.reference variables are set to null.
Here is how the full code should be implemented:-

```
 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {

 String[] movies = {"Amour", "*Argo", "Beasts of the Southern Wild", "Django Unchained", "Les Misérables", "Life of Pi", "Lincoln", "Silver Linings Playbook", "Zero Dark Thirty"};
Stack oscarStack = new Stack();

 for (String movie:movies){
oscarStack.push(movie);
}
 }
public class Stack implements StackInterface
  {


    private final int ARRAY_SIZE = MAX_SIZE;
    private String[] movies = new String[ARRAY_SIZE];   // Hold movie titles
    private int top = -1;


/**
 * Test for full stack
 */

public void push(String moviesIn)
{
    if (top >= movies.length)
            System.out.println("ERROR: Stack is full");
             return;

    top++;
    movies[top] = moviesIn;
}

/**
 * Test for empty stack
 */

public String pop()
{
    if (top == -1) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: Stack is empty");
            return " ";
    }

    top--;
    return movies[top];
}

public void peek()
{
    if(top==-1){
       System.out.println("ERROR: Stack is empty");
            return " ";

    }
else{
  return(movies[top]);
    } }}
```